# Javascript binary file reading

Tags: javascript

From [here](http://blog.vjeux.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/binaryReader.js):

```
_shl: function (a, b){
        for (++b; --b; a = ((a %= 0x7fffffff + 1) & 0x40000000) == 0x40000000 ? a * 2 : (a - 0x40000000) * 2 + 0x7fffffff + 1);
        return a;
    },

_readByte: function (i, size) {
        return this._buffer.charCodeAt(this._pos + size - i - 1) & 0xff;
    },

_readBits: function (start, length, size) {
        var offsetLeft = (start + length) % 8;
        var offsetRight = start % 8;
        var curByte = size - (start >> 3) - 1;
        var lastByte = size + (-(start + length) >> 3);
        var diff = curByte - lastByte;

        var sum = (this._readByte(curByte, size) >> offsetRight) & ((1 << (diff ? 8 - offsetRight : length)) - 1);

        if (diff && offsetLeft) {
            sum += (this._readByte(lastByte++, size) & ((1 << offsetLeft) - 1)) << (diff-- << 3) - offsetRight; 
        }

        while (diff) {
            sum += this._shl(this._readByte(lastByte++, size), (diff-- << 3) - offsetRight);
        }

        return sum;
    },
```

This code does binary file reading. Unfortunately this code isn't documented.
I would like to understand how it works. (especially _readBits and _shl methods)
In _readBits what's offsetright for? also curByte and lastByte:
i thought this way about it:

_readBits(0,16,2) curByte becomes 1. lastByte becomes 0. Why is lastByte  less than curByte? Or i made a mistake? Where? Please, help!

Comment: @Bakudan-ханювиги this isn't strange at all, take notice that `++b` is only executed once.

Comment: I prefer binaryAjax.js - http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/binaryajax/binaryajax.js - And you can find some help for it on its site.

Answer (score 0):

- `_readByte(i, size)`: `size` is the buffer length in byte, `i` is the **reversed index** (index from the end of the buffer, not from the start) of the byte which you want to read.
- `_readBits(start, length, size)`: `size` is the buffer length in byte, `length` is the number of bits which you want to read, `start` is the the **index** of the first bit which you want to read.
- `_shl(a, b)`: convert read byte `a` to actual value based on its index `b`.

Because `_readByte` use reversed index, so `lastByte` less than `curByte`.

`offsetLeft` and `offsetRight` are used to remove unrelated bits (bits not in read range) from `lastByte` and `curByte` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how cross-browser the code is. I've used the method below for reading binary data. IE has some issues that can't be resolved with only Javascript, you need a small helper function written in VB. [Here](https://gist.github.com/161492) is a fully cross browser binary reader class. If you just want the bits that matter without all the helper functionality, just add this to the end of your class that needs to read binary:

```
// Add the helper functions in vbscript for IE browsers
// From https://gist.github.com/161492
if ($.browser.msie) {
    document.write(
        "<script type='text/vbscript'>\r\n"
        + "Function IEBinary_getByteAt(strBinary, iOffset)\r\n"
        + " IEBinary_getByteAt = AscB(MidB(strBinary,iOffset+1,1))\r\n"
        + "End Function\r\n"
        + "Function IEBinary_getLength(strBinary)\r\n"
        + " IEBinary_getLength = LenB(strBinary)\r\n"
        + "End Function\r\n"
        + "</script>\r\n"
    );
}
```

Then you can pick whats right in your class add:

```
// Define the binary accessor function
if ($.browser.msie) {
        this.getByteAt = function(binData, offset) {
        return IEBinary_getByteAt(binData, offset);
    }
} else {
    this.getByteAt = function(binData, offset) {
        return binData.charCodeAt(offset) & 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Now you can read the bytes all you want

```
var byte = getByteAt.call(this, rawData, dataPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this one and it is very well documented: https://github.com/vjeux/jParser