# Understanding javascript binary parser

Tags: javascript, binary

In looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074035/javascript-binary-file-reading) I was trying to figure out this function

```
_shl: function (a, b){
  for (++b; --b; a = ((a %= 0x7fffffff + 1) & 0x40000000) == 0x40000000 ? a * 2 : (a - 0x40000000) * 2 + 0x7fffffff + 1);
  return a;
}
```

I figured out the javascript syntax and also found an uncompressed version of the function used in a md5 [javascript implementation](http://www.meta-language.net/cvs/~checkout~/forms/md5.js?f=c)

```
function shl1(a) {
  a=a%(0x7fffffff+1);
  if (a&0x40000000==0x40000000)
  {
    a-=0x40000000;  
    a*=2;
    a+=(0x7fffffff+1);
  } else
    a*=2;
  return a;
}

function shl(a,b) {
  a=integer(a);
  b=integer(b);
  for (var i=0;i<b;i++) a=shl1(a);
  return a;
}
```

My question is what is significant about `0x40000000` and `0x7fffffff`.  I somewhat understand the idea of a bitwise shift, but I am lost about the importance of these two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x7fffffff` is, in binary, a `0` followed by 31 `1`s.  Adding one to it gives `0x80000000`, a `1` followed by 31 `0`s.  I don't know why the direct constant isn't there.  `%`ing by `0x80000000` will cut off the 32nd and all higher bits.

The `0x40000000` is, in binary, a `0`, a `1`, and then 30 `0`s.  `&`ing with `0x40000000` and checking for equality to `0x40000000` checks whether that 31st bit (counting from the right this time) is set.

As far as I can tell, the section `(a - 0x40000000) * 2 + 0x7fffffff + 1)` should be the same as `a`.  Not sure why the extended code is required.

Answer (score 1):

`0x7fffffff` represents the first 31 bits of `1` (reading from RHS). So `0x7fffffff+1` is 32 bits `1`'s.

`0x40000000` represents `1000000000000000000000000000000` where the `1` is the 31st bit (reading RTL).

This has to do with manipulating 32 bit data block, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that you listed are hash generators. They're generating an unique number based on the value received.

In Javascript '0x' is the prefix for an hexadecimal number.

0x40000000 is 1 GB.
0x7fffffff = 2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647 
The number 2,147,483,647 is also the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer in computing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte