# ± data display some garbage value on html page

Tags: html, oracle, meta-tags

I have store some data in oracle as a blob type. it contains some ±  symbols. but when it render on html it display some garbage(block type) value. 
following is meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
```

My json response data ("±") display correctly but when it renders on UI it display some garbage value.

Should I need to mentioned some thing on UI side.

After changing character set to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

It display properly. But I dont want to change it.

Comment: Could you show some sample data, and the way you're displaying them?

Comment: blob data is (encrypted) binary format . I am not able to read it using sql developer.

Comment: What kind of data is it? Text? image? Reading binary from javascript requires some efforts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074035/javascript-binary-file-reading If you don't want to, you can also transform the blob into varchar2 and then read it as a string from js

Comment: @Sebas special character type. "±". Which is display some block block garbage value.(Question type)

Answer (score 0):

A BLOB (Binary Large Object) is merely a container of data. It doesn't tell you what the format of that data is. It might be a JPEG image, a Microsoft Word document, or random noise sampled from the brownian motion in a cup of tea.

Once you know the format, you can then set the content type headers accordingly and it should work fine.

Typically a BLOB will be stored in a table that includes other columns that will give you a clue about the data type.

If you can't find any info about the format, look [here](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_HTCABFF.html) for guidance (or not, as the case may be).

Comment: Thanks for info. Actually I dont know exact content type of data. which is third party db.

Comment: After analysis found that my json data display correctly but when it renders on UI it display garbage value.